# Switching ui without new window PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to change the UI without opening new windows. The problem is that when I do this on widgets then the app is not frameless. When I do it without widgets I have no idea how to change the UI.

Without widget

```
import sys, time, os


from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap



import sqlite3


class LoginMenu(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginMenu, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        uic.loadUi("LoginMenu.ui",self)
        self.clicked = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.old_pos = event.screenPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.clicked:
            dx = self.old_pos.x() - event.screenPos().x()
            dy = self.old_pos.y() - event.screenPos().y()
            self.move(self.pos().x() - dx, self.pos().y() - dy)
        self.old_pos = event.screenPos()
        self.clicked = True

        return QWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)


    
 







    

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
log = LoginMenu()
log.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

with widgets  to run app

```
import sys, time, os


from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class LogMenu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LogMenu, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("LoginMenu.ui",self)
        self.SignUp.clicked.connect(self.gotoReg)


    def gotoReg(self):
        reg=Register()
        widget.addWidget(reg)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class Register(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Register, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("SignUp.ui",self)

#main

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
log=LogMenu()
reg=Register()
widget.addWidget(log)
widget.addWidget(reg)
widget.show()


try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

sry for my eng if sth i wrote sth bad

tbh idk how to make it frameless with widgets and draggable with clicking and holding the app or switchable without using widget to run it

Comment: 1. avoid unnecessary abbreviations ("sry", "eng", "tbh"...) as they are just annoying; 2. just do that `setWindowFlags()` for the top level window; 3. if you're following a certain youtube tutorial ("code first with Hala"), I strongly suggest you to disregard it as it provides a **LOT** of terrible suggestions and bad practices.

Comment: @musicamante, Personally I dont watch the channel(or even knew of it before), but still interested in what these "false/bad suggestions" were. Any examples?

Comment: 1. the `except` doesn't catch the exception type (so if an exception actually happens, you wouldn't know why); 2. referencing a global `widget` in the instances (which will crash the program if the script is imported and not used as main); 3. constantly adding *new* widgets to QStackedWidget without keeping references. There are other serious issues in that video, like adding QDialog to QStackedWidget (which doesn't make sense), not mentioning syntax/security issues in the database. If you got your code from another source, it certainly got it from that video, and is still wrong anyway.

Comment: So how can I switch betweem UIs with the button without using the way with widgets